# Construction of a sequence + conditional convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

EDIT: I figured out a sequence that works. Thanks all.

Have a question regarding Real Analysis. I've worked hard trying to come up with a sequence which satisfies the question, but I'm not having any luck. If someone could give me a hint or point me in the right direction, that would help.

Q: Construct a sequence $a_n \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}$ such that $\sum_n \cos (a_n)$ converges conditionally

I've tried to make use of the face that $\arctan(n) \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty $, and also made use of the fact that I will need some oscillations to make the series diverge absolutely but converge conditionally, but I'm not having any luck.

Thanks

Comment: See if you can arrange to have $\cos(a_n)=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Try $a_n = \pi/2 +(-1)^n/n$

Answer (score 0):

A canonic example for conditional convergence is the sequence $a_n =(-1)^n \cdot n^{-1}$

Hint: If you could construct a sequence $x_n$ with the following requirements:
(1) $\mathrm{sign} (\cos(x_n)) = (-1)^n$ 
(2) $\dots \geq |\cos(x_n)| \geq |\cos(x_{n+1})| \geq \dots $ and $\cos(x_n) \rightarrow 0$ (Meaning it is monotonally decreasing to 0) 
(3) $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{| \cos(x_n)|}{n^{-1}} = 1 $ (Comparision test for positive series) 
 Then obviously, from (3):

$$\sum_n |\cos(x_n)| = \infty$$
And also,using (1)+(2): Leibnitz will tell us that the series $\sum_n \cos(x_n)$ converge

Comment: To get the $(-1)^n$ I'll need an $n\pi /2$ in my sequence. But, I don't know how to include that and still get it to converge to $\pi /2$. Otherwise, if I make use of trig identities, I'll need a $\sin(n\pi)$, but that will still cause problems.

Comment: @Sorey note that cosine function switches its sign in a neighbourhood of $\pi/2$. This is a very important (*and useful*) detail in the construction of the sequence.